# What is the process to form nouns from Phoenician verbs?

Tags: grammar, semitic-languages

What is the process to form nouns from Phoenician verbs?  I would like to find a nominal form of the Phoenician verb "" (nun-tsade-resh, spelled left-to-right) ("NṠR"/"naṡar") (corresponding to the English verb "triumph", with the nominal form corresponding in English to "[a] triumphing, triumph, victory").

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackExchange and did not know that translation requests were off-topic.  I do not see a StackExchange community for academic translation though?  (As opposed to general language-learning help.)  Until a Translation StackExchange community is created though, I would suggest that academic translation requests be allowed in the Linguistics StackExchange, since they are important for the fields of comparative and historical linguistics.

Comment: I have rephrased the question into a general question about Phoenician grammar instead of an off-topic translation request, and moved the original question to Yahoo! Answers: http://www.yahooanswers.com/question/index?qid=20160504194033AAbfb83

Comment: Semitic languages have more than one way of forming nouns from verb roots, so there's no guarantee that whatever noun form you came up with would correspond to a real Phoenician word.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Semitic grammar.  From the response on Yahoo! Answers though, based on comparison with Hebrew (Phoenician's closest-related major living language), it would seem that the abjadic spelling of the noun would contain the letters of the verbal root, plus an extra letter or two for an abjadic nominal suffix (with the unwritten vowels infixed).  There does not seem to be a very large body of literature surviving in Phoenician, so some nouns may very well be hypothetical, at least from a usage perspective.

Comment: Right, point being that knowing the verb root and one or more possible ways of forming nouns won't necessarily tell you how that specific noun would have been formed. If the word for victory happens not to be attested in the Phoenician corpus, then we'll never know for sure what it was, though we might be able to make educated guesses based on other Semitic languages.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using Biblical (or 'Classical') Hebrew rather than Modern Hebrew to figure out a possible noun.

Comment: I am assuming of course that noun-formation in Phoenician is a regular process, and not arbitrary per word. Is noun-formation typically a regular process in other Semitic languages? Modern and Classical (Biblical) Hebrew actually appear to be the only surviving members of the Canaanite language family, even if the latter is only used today primarily as a liturgical language. The word "victory" is available in Classical Hebrew from the Tanakh as "נִצָּחוֹן" ("nitsahon"), from the verb "נצֵּחַ" ("natséah", "to triumph"). Both words have the same three-letter abjadic root (written right-to-left).